# Pandas Groupby: Groupby conditional statement

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, latitude-longitude

I am trying to identify the location of stops from gps data but need to account for some gps drift.

I have identified stops and isolated them into a new dataframe:

```
df['Stopped'] = (df.groupby('DAY')['LAT'].diff().abs() <= 0.0005) & (df.groupby('DAY')['LNG'].diff().abs() <= 0.0005)

df2 = df.loc[(df['Stopped'] == True)]
```

Now I can label groups that have the exact match in coordinates using:

```
df2['StoppedEvent'] = df2.groupby(['LAT','LNG']).ngroup()
```

But I want to group by the same conditions of Stopped. Something like this but that works:

```
df2['StoppedEvent'] = df2.groupby((['LAT','LNG']).diff().fillna(0).abs() <= 0.0005).ngroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

```
df['Stopped'] = (df.groupby('DAY')['LAT'].diff().abs() <= 0.0005)\
                & (df.groupby('DAY')['LNG'].diff().abs() <= 0.0005)
df["Stopped_Group"] = (~df["Stopped"]).cumsum()
df2 = df.loc[df['Stopped']]
```

Now you'll have a column, `"Stopped_Group"`, which is constant within a set of rows that are close to each other as determined by your logic. In the original dataframe, `df`, this column won't have any meaning for rows that correspond to motion.

To get your desired output (if I understand you correctly), do something like the following:

```
df2["Stopped_Duration"] = df2.groupby("Stopped_Group").transform("size")
```